# Jssor limit direction of slides moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I have two slides and they move fine from first to second. 
But the problem is my chief doesn't want it move on - from second to the first back.
I looked for this option in [Jssor API](http://www.jssor.com/documentation/api.html) but didn't find anything.
Here is my code:

```
slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, $.proxy(function(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    Session.recordTime("Section " + section + ", slide " + (slideIndex + 1));
    $("#pager").text((slideIndex + 1) + "/" + $("#content").find(".slide").length);
}));
```

I'll be very appriciated for any help.
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the '$Loop' option value to false to stop the slider from looping infinitely.

Use following code to stop the slider at slide 2,

```
slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, $.proxy(function(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
    if(slideIndex == 1)
    {
        slider.$Pause();
    }
}));
```

Comment: It seems like nothing changes: the movement is still looping.
I edited:
    var options = { $AutoPlay: false, $Loop: false };

And another problem: there is no option to stop it move back from the first position? I mean: the slider starts to show first slide and I need to disallow from user the option to move leftward to the last slide.
Thank you.
Victor

Comment: You mean let the slider stop at the second slide? I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you!
I've reinstalled the version and it works!

Seems I had outdated version...